# Comparing values in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays where I need to compare values and get the duplicates. I wrote most of the code but seem to be stumped on the comparison.

Here is my code:

```
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
    for (var i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                console.log[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

compare([5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6], [6, 4, 2, 7, 10]);
```

I get the for loops to print all of the numbers, but for some reason the if statement comparison doesn't work. Is there something I am not getting about comparing values in arrays?

I am not looking for a straight up answer but guidance if possible.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sorry that was just a copying error.

Comment: Typo:  `console.log[i];` -> `console.log(i);`

Comment: You don't need a nested loop. Loop over the longest array and for each index check to see (`arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) > -1`) if it's in the second array. Output the number to a new array if it is.

Comment: @Andy, although there are [efficient libraries that have solved this problem](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection), I believe OP is trying to figure out how to handle this problem for himself.

Comment: He said "I am not looking for a straight up answer but guidance if possible." which is what I gave. In a comment.

Comment: fixing the typo fixes the code, I'm voting to close this one as [off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Andy is there a substantial gain from doing it the way you stated?

Comment: Not really @pptaszek1990. I actually prefer georg's first example if I'm honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quadratic in time since it iterates the second array for each item in the first array. A linear time solution is to convert the first array into a hash table, and then, for each item in the second one, instantly check if it is in the hash.

```js
function intersect(a, b) {
  var hash = {};
  a.forEach(function(x) { hash[x] = 1 });
  
  return b.filter(function(x) { return hash[x] === 1 });
}

c = intersect([5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6], [6, 4, 2, 7, 10]);
document.write(c)
```

Do note, however, that this only works if items to compare are primitives, you cannot put objects in a hash, so the code has to be quadratic:

```js
function intersect(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function(x) {
    return b.indexOf(x) >= 0
  });
}

a = {x:'a'};
b = {x:'b'};
c = {x:'c'};
d = {x:'d'};

i = intersect([a,b,c], [a,b,d]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(i));
```

Regarding your bit about improving your current code, I suggest that you make your javascript more idiomatic, in particular,

- get used to iteration methods instead of `for` loops
- check the repertoire of built-in functions and use them wherever possible
- and, for sanity's sake, never ever use `==`

Comment: I got your example to work but I am a bit confused as to how it works. Can you direct me to a resource so that I can read up on it? Especially the iterator methods.

Comment: @pptaszek1990: for any Javascript research, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) is always the starting point. BTW, my naming was incorrect, it's "iteration", not "iterator" methods.